# C++ dirty char*

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, char

I've this function for read photos in a directory:

```
vector<Mat> vImg;
Mat rImg;

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *file;
int count = 0;
std::vector<char*> arr; 

if(argc >= 2){
char* imgFolder = argv[1];
if ((dir = opendir(imgFolder)) != NULL) {
  while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {        
    std::string fn = file->d_name;
    std::string ext = StringToUpper(fn.substr(fn.find_last_of(".") + 1));
    if(ext == "JPG" || ext == "PNG" || ext == "JPEG") {
      count += 1;  
      char* itm = new char[100];
      strcat(itm, imgFolder);
      strcat(itm, "/");
      strcat(itm, file->d_name);
      printf("%s\n",itm);
      vImg.push_back(imread(itm));
    }
  }
  closedir (dir);
```

The problem is that after the first

```
vImg.push_back(imread(itm));
```

all other "itm" are soiled like this:

[image]

Anyone can help me, please?
Thanks! :)

Comment: any particular reason you are mixing c_strings with std::vectors and std::strings?

Comment: I don't know if that is your actual code, but you have a memory leak because you are constantly allocating a buffer of 100 `char`s and never deleting it.

Comment: I don't think it is a leak, he's probably storing them in the vector for later usage (and hopefully also to free them).

Comment: Further 100 chars is not necessarily enough. If the path and/or file name are especially long, you could experience a buffer overrun.

Comment: Usually `PATH_MAX` or `MAX_PATH` (depending on platform) is used in these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
  char* itm = new char[100];
  strcat(itm, imgFolder);  // <-- oops
```

The first `strcat` should be `strcpy`. Otherwise you're appending onto uninitialized memory.

Additionally, you never delete that `char` array anywhere.

Comment: With `delete[]`. Not `delete`.